# Python - comparing two nested lists and writing a third nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

```
some_list = [[app_num, product, prod_size, prod_amt]]
other_list = [[app_num, product, prod_size, prod_amt]]
```

I have two lists of lists. There are no matches between some_list and other_list for app_num. However, for a given app_num in other_list, the product, prod_size_ and prod_amt may be the same as in a given app_num in some_list. I am trying to create a final_some_list that is the same as some_list, except that it has deleted any list element from some_list if that list element has the same product, prod_size, and prod_amt as an element in other_list.

I have tried nested for loops, list comprehension (below are some examples of many failed attempts).

```
final_some_list = [app for app in some_list for other_app in other_list 
if not app[1] == other_app[1] and app[2] == other_app[2] and app[3] == 
other_app[3]

final_some_list = [app for app in some_list for other_app in other_list 
if not app[1] and app[2] and app[3] == in other_app
```

Comment: Can you share an example of input and desired output so that it makes easier for anyone to understand your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final_some_list = [x for x in some_list if all(x[1:] != y[1:] for y in other_list)]
```

**Edit**:

Solution above is *O*(*nm*) where `n == len(some_list)` and `m == len(other_list)`. You can make it *O*(*n* log *m*) if you want. Put all the tails of all the elements of `other_list` in a binary search tree (assuming those elements are ordable), now querying that tree is *O*(log *m*). In case the elements are hashable you can even have an *O*(*n*) solution because querying a hash-set is *O*(1).

Btw: The elements of both lists look like tuples to me, this will get you more close to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first comparison contains the `not`attribute, add != to all of the comparisons and this should work:

```
final_some_list = [app for app in some_list for other_app in other_list 
if app[1] != other_app[1] and app[2] != other_app[2] and app[3] != 
other_app[3]]
```